# How to compile Sun Pascal's module to its equivalent in Free Pascal?

Tags: pascal, porting, freepascal

I have a program written in Sun Pascal, which consists of a program unit and several module units, and I want to convert it to Free Pascal now.
So I started by testing the example in Sun Pascal 3.0.2 User's Guide(p. 52, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/801-5054/801-5054.pdf):

program unit:

```
program program_unit (output);
procedure say_hello; extern;
begin
say_hello
end.
```

module unit:

```
module module_unit;
procedure say_hello;
begin
writeln ('Hello, world.')
end;
```

I made some modifications to the source files: In program_unit, I add a line "{$link program_unit.p}", then changed the modifier "extern" to "external".

Then I tried to compiled it using fpc:

fpc program_unit.p

but it failed:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.2-8 [2014/01/22] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2012 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Linux for x86-64
Compiling program_unit.p
Linking program_unit
/usr/bin/ld.bfd: warning: link.res contains output sections; did you forget -T?
module_unit.p: file not recognized: File format not recognized
program_unit.p(6,1) Error: Error while linking
program_unit.p(6,1) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

what more modifications should I make to make the compiling work?

Comment: Before attempting to port code you need to learn both languages. That's your next step.

Comment: $link is for object files not source files

Comment: And the module shown is not any standard syntax (neither TP nor ISO/Extended Pascal), since any form of an declaration section (interface or implementation) is missing. I checked the sun manual and it seems to be its syntax, but this won't be supported by anything else since it violates basic Pascal declare before use principles.

Answer (score 1):

As David Heffernan wrote in his comment, you should learn the language, but well, here goes, to get you started.

The FreePascal equivalent of a module is a unit. The main program is not a unit, it is, well, the program (the main project file). So make your program look like:

```
program myprogram; // (output) is not required.

uses
  module_unit;

begin
  say_hello
end.
```

and your module_unit like:

```
unit module_unit;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

procedure say_hello;

implementation

procedure say_hello;
begin
  Writeln('Hello, world.')
end;

end.
```

Now just add `module_unit` to the `myprogram` project and build. Then you can run the program from the console/shell. Navigate (using `cd`) to the directory to where it is compiled, and then, on Linux or OS X, enter `./myprogram`, or in Windows, enter `myprogram` or `myprogram.exe`.

*FWIW, instead of the command line, I advise you to use the Lazarus IDE. It makes adding units, editing the program and many other things a lot easier.*